# Dealing with the Done button after Quicklook, Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, quicklook

This has got to be the dumbest question of the day, but I'm just not getting it.
I create a Quicklook, which shows just fine.  When I hit the Done button, it just reappears.  How do I intercept the Done button? Or more generally, control what is displayed in what I assume is a navbar.  Here is the relevant code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    /*
     *  get the path to the pdf resource.
     */

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"article" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURL *docURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];


    /*
     *  create the Quicklook controller.
     */

    QLPreviewController *qlController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

    PreviewItem *item = [[PreviewItem alloc] initPreviewURL:docURL WithTitle:@"Article"];
    self.pdfDatasource = [[PDFDataSource alloc] initWithPreviewItem:item];
    qlController.dataSource = self.pdfDatasource;


    /*
     *  present the document.
     */

    [self presentViewController:qlController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I assume I am missing something obvious.

Thank you,
Ken

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried Taking your ViewDidAppear code To ViewDidLoad ? As when you click on done button all the views of the Controller are being Loaded again except ViewDidLoad. So the quicklook view Appears again. Just Try

Comment: I get this warning and a blank screen:  
2017-06-19 09:24:57.080342-0700  Warning: Attempt to present <QLPreviewController: 0x102889e00> on <QuickLaunchViewController: 0x10182dfa0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

(so i never get a chance to hit the Done button).  thanks, though.

Comment: okay so i looked at the problem you are facing. you can do one thing pass a bool value for displaying the quicklook in viewDidAppear. Write your code in viewDidAppear but under a check of bool Value in viewDidLoad make bool value as 1 so the view will appear and when the view appeared on the click of done button make the bool value as 0 so the code in viewDidAppear will not load again till you don't refresh the bool to 1 and you can use this bool to 1 at any Time like when displaying a new pdf make bool as 1.

Comment: Yes, I think that will work, but I have to believe there is "correct" answer, probably something to do with delegates.  I'll give what you suggest a shot for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to roll everything back into the original viewcontroller.  That way when I hit the done button it goes back to the original viewcontroller, which is exactly what I wanted.  so instead of having a separate class, I just incorporated the calls right into my main viewcontroller.  I suspect that there is still a way to do with a cunning use of delegates, but in case anyone else is having the same issue, this was a solution that worked for me.

Thank you for your attention and help.
Ken